# My programs works but i don't know whether my source code is idle or not

Tags: if-statement, input, while-loop, printing, integer

I am learning python online and I wrote this code to find whether a number is prime number or not. The thing is what they did was very different from what I wrote in my code so can I get any suggestion to how to make my code more efficient or better? Also this isn't the only program I made there are many programs I am practicing and many of them work but I am doubting whether my method is correct and my coding is inefficient

```
n = int(input("Enter the number "))
c = 2
r= n%c
while(r>0):
    c = c+1
    r = n%c
if (c==n):
    print("The number is prime number");
else:
    print("The number you entered is not a prime number")
    print("it is divisible by ",c)
```

Comment: Remember to always tag your question with the language you are using -- [tag:python] in this case. The language tag is the most important tag to use when asking questions; without it, the question is more difficult to find (for those answering & for future viewers).

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to python, then your code is fine.
For more cleaner code, refer to below code:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number "))
c = 2
while(n%c>0):
    c = c+1    
if (c==n):
    print("The number is prime number");
else:
    print("The number you entered is not a prime number")
    print("it is divisible by ",c)
```

But if you are looking for an efficient program to find whether the number is prime or not, then you can refer to: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-check-whether-a-number-is-prime-or-not/

Answer (score -1):

you can check only n/2 insted of n